# pycuda._driver import error (Windows)

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-2013, cuda, pycuda

I am trying to run pycuda on my windows 7 machine. I have installed the following-

**1. Python 2.7.9**

**2. cuda_7.0.28_windows**

**3. numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python2.7**

**4. pycuda-2014.1+cuda6514-cp27-none-win32** (*whl from christopher gohlke's libraries page*)

**5. Visual Studio 2013 community edition**

All the above installations were successful but when I run the code below (*its a long code but the import statements should be enough to describe the problem*)

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pycuda.driver as drv
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy.testing
```

I get the following error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\trash\cuda_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pycuda.driver as drv
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycuda\driver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pycuda._driver import *  # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any idea what could the problem be??

Comment: Install CUDA 6.5.14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution involved installing the version of CUDA supported by the library. I had a higher version. The **pycuda** library's filename can be decomposed as follows to identify the versions of **CUDA** and **Python** supported by it-

```
Filename: pycuda-2014.1+cuda6514-cp27-none-win32

Python version supported: 2.7 (from cp27)
CUDA version supported: 6.5.14 (from cuda6514)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have Anaconda with python 3.5 and Cuda 7.5.18 with pycuda-2016.1+cuda7518-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl installed.

Comment: adding C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin to PATH helped.

Comment: @MichaelPogosskiy Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows10 x64